# No pip binary after installing Python 3.4.2 on Centos 6.5

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4, centos6.5

After successful installation of Python I can't find the pip executable.
The contents of the /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip are:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  9450 Oct 26 10:29 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   116 Oct 26 10:29 __main__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  9507 Oct 26 10:29 cmdoptions.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  8162 Oct 26 10:29 baseparser.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  6578 Oct 26 10:29 basecommand.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  2969 Oct 26 10:29 pep425tags.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  9455 Oct 26 10:29 log.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  6202 Oct 26 10:29 locations.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 40403 Oct 26 10:29 index.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1086 Oct 26 10:29 exceptions.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 22580 Oct 26 10:29 download.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 24172 Oct 26 10:29 util.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   116 Oct 26 10:29 status_codes.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   431 Oct 26 10:29 runner.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 83557 Oct 26 10:29 req.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 20618 Oct 26 10:29 wheel.py
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Oct 26 10:29 vcs
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Oct 26 10:29 commands
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root  4096 Oct 26 10:29 _vendor
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Oct 26 10:29 backwardcompat
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Oct 26 10:29 __pycache__
```

How can I use it?

Comment: It should be in /usr/bin/. You can use it directly anywhere. Try `pip freeze`

Comment: @ChillarAnand I've checked that already: [andrzej@localhost pip]$ which pip
/usr/bin/which: no pip in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/andrzej/bin)

Comment: Is `pip freeze` working correctly. Try `whereis pip`

Comment: OK, it's called now 'pip3.4' Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: [andrzej@localhost pip]$ whereis pip
pip: /usr/local/bin/pip3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html

> pip is the preferred installer program. Starting with Python 3.4, it
>   is included by default with the Python binary installers.

Before python 3.4, pip was a 'seperate package' and was just called 'pip'.
Because they have now included it with the python installer, and other versions of pip might have been previously installed on the system, the new pip that comes with python 3.4 was named pip3.4 to be able to easily distinguish between different pip versions.

Also see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html and http://bugs.python.org/issue20139