# PIL with Centos 7 and Python 3.4

Tags: python, linux, centos, python-imaging-library, centos7

Does anyone have a working implementation of [PIL](http://python-pillow.github.io/) with Centos 7 and Python 3.4?

I tried to install the [tarball](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/P/Pillow/Pillow-3.0.0.tar.gz#md5=fc8ac44e93da09678eac7e30c9b7377d) from here, but when running "make" or "make test" got a lot of errors.

If anyone has a working implementation, could you please post the commands and configuration needed `i.e. yum packages` to get it to work?

I also found this [blog post](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/install-pil-into-centos-7-for-openeerp-7-ioerror-decoder-zip-not-available-83174#post_reply) but it didn't help.

Here is one error that I am seeing when trying to `convert a jpeg's size`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/var/www/deploy/myproject/myproject-django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1557, in resize
    self.load()
  File "/var/www/deploy/myproject/myproject-django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 203, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
  File "/var/www/deploy/myproject/myproject-django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 420, in _getdecoder
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
OSError: decoder jpeg not available
```

Comment: What are the build errors? Do you have the appropriate `python-devel` package installed?

Comment: @PaulRooney I added an error above when trying to run a common `PIL` method.  I have `Package python-devel-2.7.5-18.el7_1.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version` and `Package python-pillow-2.0.0-17.gitd1c6db8.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version`.  So, I think that I am good there.  I think that it is just Centos 7 + Python 3.4...

Comment: Try installing the `libjpeg-devel` package and then install pillow using pip3. If you don't have pip3 look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618686/how-to-install-pip-in-centos-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you install the dependencies first, and then reinstall Pillow. Looks like you're missing libjpeg. See here for details.

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/installation.html