# How to properly install python3 on Centos 7

Tags: python, centos

I'm running Centos7 and it comes with Python2.  I installed python3, however when I install modules with pip, python3 doesn't use them.  I can run python3 by typing python3 at the CLI

python (2.x) is located in /usr/bin/python
python3 is located in /usr/local/bin/python3

I tried creating a link to python3 in /usr/bin/ as "python", but as expected, it didnt resolve anything. I renamed the current python to python2.bak It actually broke some command line functionality (tab to complete). I had to undo those changes to resolve.

Suggestions welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: use pip3 as well and keep both versions

Comment: I don't have pip3 and it doesnt exist in the repo.. hmmm..

Comment: if you install python3 you'll have it

Comment: python3 is installed, i've been using it. still no pip3 though :(

Comment: ok, use pip from the python3 directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IUS](https://ius.io) project has ready to go RPM packages of python34u-pip, python35u-pip, and python36u-pip.  These will give you corresponding `pip3.4`, `pip3.5`, and `pip3.6` commands.  As expected, the packages installed by those will be available to the corresponding `python3.4`, `python3.5`, and `python3.6` interpreters.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `pip` for `python3`, too? Try `pip3` rather than `pip`. I assume your regular `pip` is just installing the modules for Python 2.x.

Comment: I don't have pip3 and it doesnt exist in the repo.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618686/how-to-install-pip-in-centos-7. You may need to change `3.4` to `3.5` though, depending on which version of Python you have.

Comment: Also try pip34 or pip35 (or whichever Python 3.x you are using)